# Localized web.config settings remembered

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I've deployed a project on a remote server for testing between myself and a QA team. All of us are able to test just fine except for one individual who is still connecting with a connection string that was present in a previous version of the web.config. This change to the web.config occurred on Friday, at which point I rebooted IIS to clear the get a fresh read of all the files, and that seemed to work just fine. Come Monday morning, though, the problem returned. Could anyone tell me why this would happen to one individual, even after clearing everything from IIS? I can't imagine anything related to Web.config would be stored locally on a users machine, but I'm at a loss. I should note that I use a different web.config locally than I do on the test server, so after I publish the files, I just overwrite my version with a backup of the version used on the test environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your connection string in the mySettings Section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably find in you settings.Settings.cs, there is a default setting value**

```
 [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString)]
    **[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("server=.")]**
    public string TEst {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["TEst"]));
        }
    }
```

I would make sure the correct version of the application is deployed for this user.

Cheers

Iain

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I don't think it's anything to do with the hard code, since it works for everybody except this one person. Another IIS restart fixed the problem and it's still working fine 24 hours later. I'll consider this a fluke, I suppose...